# Add y-axis-values to ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-point

Say I have a ggplot, with a continuous variable allocated to the y-axis and a geom_point layer. How would I add the y-axis-value corresponding to each point to the ggplot as an additional layer?

**EDIT:**

For clarification: Next to each point, I'd like to see a number. That number should be the value of the y-variable that corresponds to the respective point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks weird but seems to be in line with your question

```
### Library
library(ggplot2)

### Initiating data
set.seed(2)
df <- data.frame(y=rnorm(10), 
                 x=rnorm(10))

### Display plot
ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis=sec_axis(~., 
                                     breaks=round(df$y, 2), 
                                     labels=round(df$y, 2), name="Additional y axis"))
```

[image]

**EDIT**

Based on your edit, please find the code to put y values next to each dot.

```
### Library
library(ggplot2)

### Initiating data
set.seed(2)
df <- data.frame(y=rnorm(10), 
                 x=rnorm(10))

### Display plot
ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  geom_text(x=df$x+0.1, y=df$y, label=round(df$y, 2))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, though what I meant was I want the value of the y-variable next to the corresponding point, like directly next to the point.

Comment: @RibbitRibbit I updated the code, is that what you were looking for?